# Selenium 2 and html tables

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Just wondering if there is a better way to get values from a table in selenium 2.  I am currently using 2 for loops I loop over each TR and within each TR I loop over all TD.  so for example if I have a table row with 10 columns I loop 10 times and pull out the text value.  That seems clunky to me.

My table Rows looks like so

```
<tr id="cTestData" class="odd">
<td class="date_activated">08/31/2011</td>
<td class="date_redeemed"> Not redeemed * </td>
<td class="expiration_date">09/01/2011</td>
<td class="product"> State of Maine </td>
<td class="value">$1.00</td>
<td class="store"> &ndash; &ndash; &ndash; </td>
<td class="offer_details">
</tr>
```

I think I should be able to say for each table Row get me the TD element with class = date_activated and have it return the date. I tried a few things but nothing seemed to work based on TD class name = foo

If it helps my actual code is

```
for(WebElement trElement : tr_collection)
        {
            List<WebElement> td_collection=trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
            System.out.println("NUMBER OF COLUMNS="+td_collection.size());
            col_num=1;          
            HashMap actInfo = new HashMap();  // new hashmap for each line inthe result set

            if(!td_collection.isEmpty() && td_collection.size() != 1 ){  
                for(WebElement tdElement : td_collection)
                {
                        System.out.println("Node Name=== " + tdElement.getAttribute("class")); 
                        System.out.println("Node Value=== " + tdElement.getText());
                        actInfo.put(tdElement.getAttribute("class"), tdElement.getText());
                    col_num++;
                }
                masterMap.add(actInfo);
            } // end if

            row_num++;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@class='foo']/td[@class='date_activated']"))
```

That will return all the TD elements with the class `date_activated` with a parent row with class `foo`. You can then loop through the elements and use `getText` to get the dates. This works from the **root** of the page.

If you would like to do it from each **TR element**, try:

```
trElement.findElement(By.xpath("./td[@class='date_activated']")).getText()
```

Comment: I typically try to avoid xpaths but that worked fine until I figure out a nicer solution.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to work with tables as a table.  You still have to use the XPath, but it's limited to the table.

```
IWebElement table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("TableId")); //Get Table 
List<IWebElement> Rows = new List<IWebElement>(table.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tbody/tr")));
List<List<IWebElement>> table_element = new List<List<IWebElement>>(); 
for (int k = 0; k < Rows.Count; k++)
{                 
    table_element.Add(new List<IWebElement>(Rows[k].FindElements(By.XPath("./td")))); //Get all Elements from Rows
}

for (int k = 0; k < table_element[0].Count; k++)
{
    if (table_element[0][k].Text == "08/31/2011")
    {
        table_element[0][k].Click();               
    }            
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use a css selector, try:

`List<WebElement> myTds = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#tableId .date_activated"));`

Note the space in `"#tableId .date_activated"`.

This will select all the elements with class `date_activated` within a table with an id `tableId`. You will still need to loop over this list to get the text of each of your cells.

A little simpler selector might be sufficient:

`driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".date_activated"))`

This will find *all* the elements with class `date_activated` on your page.