# Iterate through table in Selenium 2 WebDriver (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I have the following table layout in HTML (which changes accordingly):

```
<table class="other-table-style">

    <tr> 
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" width="30%">Joe</td>
      <td align="center" width="30%">Bloggs</td>
      <td align="center" width="40%">28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" width="30%">John</td>
      <td align="center" width="30%">Doe</td>
      <td align="center" width="40%">30</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I want to be able to iterate through this using Selenium 2.0 WebDriver, but I have not been able to find any good examples.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Have a look at [`find_elements_by*()` methods](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html).

Comment: I've trying using find_elements_by_xpath, but i'm not getting anything back.  I've tried this on just the table and that works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Used:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

trs = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr") 

tds = trs[1].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
```

This allows looping through each one to do as desired.

Comment: and cell value is like `tds[0].text`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the person who posted [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503582/selenium-2-and-html-tables) had code that would get you on the right track:

```
for (WebElement trElement : tr_collection) {
    List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
    System.out.println("NUMBER OF COLUMNS = " + td_collection.size());
    col_num = 1;          

    if (!td_collection.isEmpty() && td_collection.size() != 1 ) {  
        for (WebElement tdElement : td_collection) {
            System.out.println("Node Name=== " + tdElement.getAttribute("class")); 
            System.out.println("Node Value=== " + tdElement.getText());
            col_num++;
        }
    }

    row_num++;
}
```

**Edit:** I changed their code somewhat... they were accumulating the class of each td and the text it contained in a hashmap and then once they had gone through the entire table, adding that into a master hashmap. Also this is the Java variant of Selenium so you would have to port it over. The guts of it remain the same though - perhaps someone with more Selenium experience could give more info... I prefer to live over in `WATIR`land myself.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an excellent tutorial for parsing tables (and links) using selenium](http://www.guru99.com/accessing-links-tables-selenium-webdriver.html). Though it is written in Java, the translation into Python is quite trivial.

for instance, to read row 2 column 2 of a table with the Python version of Selenium (2.41):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie()

# assuming you're connected to your web page of interest, do:
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')
```